# ¿Como extraer varios datos string por cada observacion de una columna en un data frame en R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ciencia-de-datos

me pueden ayudar por favor con una duda en lenguaje R:
tengo un data frame con la siguiente estructura:

| proyecto | Región(es) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a, b, c |
| 3 | c, d |

y quiero que quede de la siguiente forma:

| proyecto | Región 1 | Región 2 | Región 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | NA | NA |
| 2 | a | b | c |
| 3 | c | d | NA |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más directa es con la función `separate()` de la librería `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(proyecto = 1:3, región = c("a,b", "a,b,c", "c,d")) %>% 
  separate(col = región,   #La columna a separar
    into = c("Región 1", "Región 2", "Región 3") #Un vector de caracteres con los nombres de las columnas que se crearán
          )
```

Super simple.

No sé si R base o alguna otra librería implementa algo así. En R base se me ocurrió esta alternativa, que se me hace muy complicada:

```
#los datos se llaman foo
as.data.frame(
  matrix(
    unlist(
      lapply(
        str_split(foo$región, ","), `length<-`, 3)), 
  ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
)
```